# Cannot retrieve multiple values from a listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I am populating a listBox at runtime from a database as follows:

```
List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES> ReportTypes = GetReportTypesFromDatabase(ReportMappingIds)
BindingList<FILE_REPORT_TYPES> pbReportTypesBindingList = new BindingList<FILE_REPORT_TYPES>(ReportTypes);

listBoxReports.DataSource = ReportTypesBindingList;
listBoxReports.DisplayMember = "REPORT_DESCRIPTION";
listBoxReports.ValueMember = "REPORT_ID";
```

I then would like select multiple items on the listBox when running the windows form and retrieve each individual Value of my selections. If only one selection is made one could do the following:

```
listBoxReports.SelectedValue;
```

I would like to do the following:

```
var list = listBoxReports.SelectedValues;
```

However this is not allowed i.e. "SelectedValues" does not exist.

Some people are erroneously suggesting that in this particular case SelectedIndices may be used. It cannot be used, I am trying to retrieve the "VALUE". This cannot be done (in this particular case):

```
listBox.Items[i].Value;
```

**I think the solution should be along the lines of:**

```
    foreach(var line in listBox.Items)
       {
           var res= ((SOME CASTING)line).Value;
       }
```

Comment: What is `ReportTypesBindingList`? It is not `pbReportTypesBindingList`, is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected items you have 2 options

a.) ListBox.SelectedIndices which returns the indices of the selected items which you then need to use to look up in the Items property what the value is or

b.) ListBox.SelectedItems which returns you a collection with the selected items themselves (be aware that it is an objectlist so you need to transform the items into your appropriate datatype).

Edit: With the additional information the following is possible

```
List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES> mySelectedList = new List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES>();
foreach (Object selectedItem in ListBox.SelectedItems)
{
    mySelectedList.Add( ((FILE_REPORT_TYPES)selectedItem) );
}
```

Comment: After you create SelectedItems the VALUE cannot be extracted.

Comment: what do you mean there with VALUE cannot be extracted? the value of the single elements themselves? (that should not be the case as the selecteditems and also the items collection itself are only references to the items in question)

Comment: Ah saw your update that is the case then because you need to transform the item into a meaningful datatype which has the property value. you get them back as OBJECT and as nothing else so you need to transform them

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the datatype I could use? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% as you are using different datatypes there with similar names. List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES> selectedList = (List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES>) ListBox.SelectedItems; could do the work there for getting a list of the selected items with the appropriate type.

Comment: I put a foreach method into the answer as I'm not 100% about the list conversion (it should work but didn't try it out, the other method...the one I put into the answer is what I know that should work out)

Comment: `foreach(FILE_REPORT_TYPES type in listBox.SelectedItems)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ListBox.SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [`ListBox.SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to get  all selected-items, you can let the `foreach` cast:

```
foreach(FILE_REPORT_TYPES frt in listBox.SelectedItems)
{
   // ...
}
```

or if you want to get the `ReportID` into a list with the help of LINQ:

```
List<decimal> reportIds = listBox.SelectedItems.Cast<FILE_REPORT_TYPES>()
    .Select(frt => frt.REPORT_ID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Becuase of the data binding this does not work, i am unable to retrieve the "value" after indexing

Comment: +1 for the foreach cast. Didn't know that that possibility exists. cool!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the selected value you could do the following

```
listBoxReports.SelectedItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like below

```
   List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES> reportList = new List<FILE_REPORT_TYPES>();

   foreach(var item in listBox.SelectedItems)
   {        
        reportList.Add((FILE_REPORT_TYPES)item);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer (the casting is the trick):

```
List<decimal> reportIds = new List<decimal>();

foreach(var line in listBoxReports.SelectedItems)
{
    reportIds.Add(((PB_FILE_REPORT_TYPES)line).REPORT_ID); 
}
```